# How to fix header getting pushed downwards in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm having issues with the header, there is a header that appeared out of nowhere, and every single header is set to null, and still no clue where it is located, this is my file:

as you can see, all the headers i set where pushed downwards

this wasn't happening before, until i added the drawer navigation, not sure how to fix it, since i picked someone else's method

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen
},{
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    header: null
    //headerStyle: { height: 150, borderBottomLeftRadius: 25, borderBottomRightRadius: 25, overflow: "hidden", backgroundColor: "blue" },
  }
});

const VacationsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Vacations: VacationsScreen,
  Request: RequestScreen
},{
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    header: null
    //headerBackground: <Image style={ StyleSheet.absolutefill } source={ require('../assets/images/Header/background_image.png') }/>
  },
    //headerTintColor: "#FFF",
    //title: "Vacaciones"
  }
);

const HourAllocationsStack = createStackNavigator({
  HourAllocations: HourAllocationsScreen,
  Allocations: AllocationsScreen
},{
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    header: null
    //headerBackground: <Image style={ StyleSheet.absolutefill } source={ require('../assets/images/Header/background_image.png') }/>
  },
    //headerTintColor: "#FFF",
    //title: "Registro"
  }
);

const ExpensesStack = createStackNavigator({
  Expenses: ExpensesScreen
},{
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    header: null
    //headerBackground: <Image style={ StyleSheet.absolutefill } source={ require('../assets/images/Header/background_image.png') }/>
  },
    //headerTintColor: "#FFF",
    //title: "Rendir"
  }
);

const CertificatesStack = createStackNavigator({
  Certificates: CertificatesScreen
},{
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    header: null
    //headerBackground: <Image style={ StyleSheet.absolutefill } source={ require('../assets/images/Header/background_image.png') }/>
  },
    //headerTintColor: "#FFF",
    //title: "Certificados"
  }
);

const MainApp = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: HomeStack,
  Vacations: VacationsStack,
  HourAllocations: HourAllocationsStack,
  Expenses: ExpensesStack,
  Certificates: CertificatesStack
},{
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: () => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state;
      if (routeName === "Home") {
        return (
          <Icon name="home" size={ 25 } color="gray"/>
        );
      }
      if (routeName === "Vacations") {
        return (
          <Icon5 name="sun" solid size={ 25 } color="gray"/>
        );
      }
      if (routeName === "Expenses") {
        return (
          <Icon5 name="plane" size={ 25 } color="gray"/>
        );
      }
      if (routeName === "Certificates") {
        return(
          <Icon name="bill" size={ 25 } color="gray"/>
        );
      }
      if (routeName === "HourAllocations") {
        return(
          <Icon name="clock" solid size={ 25 } color="gray"/>
        );
      }
    }
  }),
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: "#FF6F00",
    inactiveTintColor: "#263238"
  },
});

const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
  User: UserScreen,
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
  MainTab: MainApp
},{
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    header: null
  },
  hideStatusBar: true,
  drawerBackgroundColor: "#FFF",
  overlayColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: "rgba(8, 192, 245, 0.5)",
    activeBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
  },
  initialRouteName : "MainTab"
})

const MainStack = createStackNavigator({
  MainScreen: DrawerNavigation,
},{
  initialRouteName : "MainScreen" 
});

export default createAppContainer(MainStack);
```

[image: iphone emulator]

EDIT: I tested by hiding the header in the drawer navigator, and still nothing

```
const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
  User: UserScreen,
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
  MainTab: MainApp
},{
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    header: null
  },
  hideStatusBar: true,
  drawerPosition: "right",
  drawerBackgroundColor: "#FFF",
  overlayColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: "rgba(8, 192, 245, 0.5)",
    activeBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)",
  },
  initialRouteName : "MainTab"
})
```